# HOWTO organize hierarchical groups and ACLs in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, groups, acl, roles

We are currently using CiviCRM ver. 5.35.1 on WordPress ver. 5.7.1.

All our contacts and organizations are included in groups related to (Italian) Regions, with Provinces within (the same organization as States and Counties in USA).
We have therefore created a groups hierarchy, organized as follows:

```
Country
+-- Region1
    +-- Province1
    +-- Province2
+-- Region2
    +-- Province3
    +-- Province4
    +-- Province5
+-- Region3
    +-- Province6
etc...
```

We need to show, using the ACLs and Roles, ONLY the Province contacts and organizations to a provincial coordinator, and all the Region contacts and organizations of a regional coordinator.
All contacts and organizations are already member of their province.

We are playing on it without success. Could you help us? TIA.

Comment: alternative approach is doing this via relationships - using our extension https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.relatedpermissions can work multi-level. also this one though have not used it as ours has done everything we required. https://github.com/agiliway/com.agiliway.custompermission